# How to eliminate/deactivate Ubuntu One account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I want to eliminate my account since I created it only as a trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/HowDoIDowngradeCancelMyAccount)

**How do I downgrade or cancel my Ubuntu One account?**

Do you want to either downgrade or cancel you Ubuntu One plan? Both the downgrade and cancel options are available in the Account area. Click on "View/Edit" and you will find links to downgrade or cancel your subscription.